# Return code is always 0 after running echo "\$ macroName " | ftp -i mymachine

Tags: solaris, ftp, exit-status

I cannot seem to retrieve a non-zero return code when calling the ftp macro. It doesn't matter what errors are encountered during the ftp macro execution e.g. directory doesn't exist, file doesn't exists etc.

I'd love to know why.

I'm using bash on Solaris.

My `.netrc` file looks like so:

```
machine myftp1
        login xxxxxxxx
        password xxxxxxxxx

macdef getASCIIfiles
       cd $1
       hash
       prompt off
       get $2
```

Executing the following commands

```
echo "\$ getASCIIfiles Scratch/mydir NON_EXISTANT_FILE.TXT" | ftp -i myftp1    
echo $?
```

produces the following output

```
Hash mark printing on (8192 bytes/hash mark).    
Interactive mode on.    
NON_EXISTANT_FILE.TXT: The system cannot find the file specified.    
0
```

Why is zero being returned?

Comment: Maybe use `wget` or `curl` instead of `ftp`?

Comment: @Barmar It is a legacy system; moving away from ftp is not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'ftp' command does not seem to return other error codes than 0.

An alternative solution would be to check the FTP return codes.
There is some examples in how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442763